# Luigi server not reachable from python

Tags: python, http, urllib, luigi

I have a fresh Windows 10 installation with a miniconda env (py34) with luigi installed. When I run `luigid` in command prompt it starts the scheduler, and when I open `localhost:8082` in chrome it shows my the web front of the scheduler.

However, when I try to run a task to the scheduler (in python from PyCharm), I seem not to be able to connect. The error I am getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MiniConda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\luigi\rpc.py", line 125, in _fetch
    response = self._fetcher.fetch(full_url, body, self._connect_timeout)
  File "C:\MiniConda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\luigi\rpc.py", line 75, in fetch
    return urlopen(full_url, body, timeout).read().decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\MiniConda3\envs\py34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\MiniConda3\envs\py34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\MiniConda3\envs\py34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\MiniConda3\envs\py34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\MiniConda3\envs\py34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\MiniConda3\envs\py34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authorization Required
10:10:15.217 [   INFO] [luigi-interface] Retrying...
10:10:16.202 [  ERROR] [luigi-interface] Failed connecting to remote scheduler 'http://localhost:8082'
```

A similar setup on a windows 7 machine works like that.

Anyone any ideas what might be causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solved by disabling HTTP(S)_PROXY environment variable. In cmd (or in PyCharm terminal in Windows) before scheduling the job, enter following:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=
set HTTPS_PROXY=
```

That unsets proxies for the session.
For instance, here is a .bat file, that i'm using:

```
CALL "venv/Scripts/activate.bat"

set HTTP_PROXY=
set HTTPS_PROXY=

python -m luigi --module YourModule YourFeature

CALL deactivate
```